# Input automatic replacement not working in 12.3 or 12.3.1

Tags: replacement, input, version-12.3

After installing Mathematica 12.3 (and now with 12.3.1) in Windows 10, the default automatic replacements like "->", ">=", "!=", etc. stop working.

```
Options[SelectedNotebook[], InputAutoReplacements]
```

Returns

```
{InputAutoReplacements -> {}}
```

Edit: Apparently the new behavior is that the characters aren't replaced, but are rendered differently (when the cursor in not there).

So my problem then is that this new functionality is not working for me. `->` is rendered as `->`, `>=` is rendered as `>=`, etc.

In my system

`CurrentValue[AutoOperatorRenderings]`

returns

`Inherited`

And

`Options[SelectedNotebook[], AutoOperatorRenderings]`

returns

`{AutoOperatorRenderings -> {}}`

Comment: Are you sure you want the old behaviour back?  See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246400/in-v-12-3-expression-in-notebook-shakes-when-scrolling-mouse-to-edit-them-how for further discussion.

Comment: Are you using a custom stylesheet for your notebook? Also, can you try to reset all your preferences as described [here](https://support.wolfram.com/12464)? (Be sure to rename the directory instead of deleting it, so you can easily revert the change)

Comment: @LukasLang Reseting the preferences worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The functionality of `InputAutoReplacements` has been replaced by the (much nicer in my opinion) [`AutoOperatorRenderings`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AutoOperatorRenderings.html) functionality:

[image]

Notice how the operators are instantly replaced by their nicely-displayed variants, but the can still be easily edited.

On a fresh install of 12.3, the relevant setting contains these substitutions:

```
CurrentValue[AutoOperatorRenderings]
(* <|
  "|->"->"\[Function]",
  "->"->"\[Rule]",
  ":>"->"\[RuleDelayed]",
  "<="->"\[LessEqual]",
  ">="->"\[GreaterEqual]",
  "!="->"\[NotEqual]",
  "=="->"\[Equal]",
  "<->"->"\[TwoWayRule]",
  "[["->"\[LeftDoubleBracket]",
  "]]"->"\[RightDoubleBracket]",
  "<|"->"\[LeftAssociation]",
  "|>"->"\[RightAssociation]"
|> *)
```

[image]

If the result is something else on your system, you can try to reset your preferences as described [here](https://support.wolfram.com/12464). (Be sure to rename the directory instead of deleting it, then you can easily go back if it doesn't work)

Comment: Ok. I also think that this new functionality would be better... if it worked. So the problem is that this new behavior is not working for me. `->` renders like `->`, not like an arrow that change back when I put the cursor there.

Comment: @jjagmath Does `CurrentValue[AutoOperatorRenderings]` return the same thing for you as shown in my answer?

Comment: No, see my updated question.

Comment: @Lukas Lang it is fantastic that you show what the output is for `CurrentValue[AutoOperatorRenderings]`! Can you, please, make this into an easily copy-and-paste-able format? It would be of great value to anyone that encounters these troubles.

Comment: @CATrevillian I have included a version that should be copy-and-paste-able

Comment: @LukasLang You should include your suggestion of resetting the preferences here in the answer. That was what fixed the problem.  Then I could accept your answer.

Comment: @jjagmath good point - I have updated the answer with a link to the knowledge base article

Comment: As a voyage of discovery, I tried removing the identified folders sequentially, and I found that the problem folder was `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica`. Also, a warning: if you delete `C:\ProgramData\Mathematica`, you must resupply your activiation key.