# Having special characters render as you type

Tags: editing, named-characters

It used to be that if I typed `==` or `->` these would automatically be rendered as `\[Equal]` and `\[Rule]`.

Now, for some reason, this feature has disappeared in 12.3.1.

I would like to have it back but I can't find any relevant option neither in the Settings nor in the Options Inspector.

I can still obtain what I want by typing <kbd>esc</kbd>`->`<kbd>esc</kbd> etc... But this is cumbersome.

Comment: I not using 12.3.1 yet, but i guess you can still edit *KeyEventTranslations.tr* to add key bindings. For part I use: `Item[KeyEvent["i", Modifiers -> {Control, Command}], FrontEndExecute[{FrontEnd``NotebookWrite[FrontEnd``InputNotebook[], "\[LeftDoubleBracket]",  After]}]]` and similar for the right one to write them with alt gr+i/o

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Though this doesn't quite achieve what it used to be because 1. The Rule character should be rendered after two keystrokes and 2. in principle they don't need to be in sequence. I can type a `-`, come back, type `>`+space and it works.

Comment: You  look for InputAutoReplacements. Try CurrentValue@InputAutoReplacements. If it returns {} then effectively your InputAutoReplacements must be restored. Tell me the results of your tests

Comment: @hieron That was it. You solved it. If you can make it into an answer I'll accept it. If you can further copy-paste your current setting I will be eternally grateful and, of course, upvote it.

Comment: So far, this question has been asked at least 2 other times & the answers do not show how to successfully change the setting that dictates the auto replacements to occur. I’ve not had any success with such things myself using any of the answers. I’ve also been lazy to post a question about this. Looking forward to the answer from @hieron to address these shortcomings!

Comment: Thanks to their comment I was able to fix it, so if they don't answer I will self-answer eventually

Comment: IIRC, `InputAutoReplacements` was deprecated in favor of the new ligatures.  So having it set to an empty list is expected.  If you've manually turned ligatures off, then you would need to restore these.  If you didn't, then you might want to reset the StyleHints option at the Global scope.

Comment: @ihojnicki:  Ok, that's new. But why the deprecation is not documented. And where can I turn the ligatures off/on?

Comment: The option is still there and it still works, it just interferes with ligature support.  So maybe obsoleted is a better choice of word.  As for disabling ligatures, that is accomplished via `CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {StyleHints, "OperatorRenderings"}] = {}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I can't test it in MMA 12.3, (my version 12.1) try this>

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
 InputAutoReplacements -> {"->" -> "\[Rule]", 
   ":>" -> "\[RuleDelayed]", "<=" -> "\[LessEqual]", 
   ">=" -> "\[GreaterEqual]", "!=" -> "\[NotEqual]", 
   "==" -> "\[Equal]", "@>" -> "\[InlinePart]", 
   "<->" -> "\[TwoWayRule]", ParentList}]
```

To get the current setting you type

```
CurrentValue[InputAutoReplacements]
```

To restore the original setting made in $FrontEnd

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, InputAutoReplacements -> Inherited]
```

Answer (score 3):

I discovered [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/251013/55861) afterwards.

It turns out that that didn't work for me. I had to set this option instead

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {StyleHints, "OperatorRenderings"}] = <|
  "|->" -> "\[Function]", 
  "->" -> "\[Rule]",
  ":>" -> "\[RuleDelayed]",
  "<=" -> "\[LessEqual]",
  ">=" -> "\[GreaterEqual]",
  "!=" -> "\[NotEqual]", 
  "==" -> "\[Equal]",
  "<->" -> "\[TwoWayRule]", 
  "[[" -> "\[LeftDoubleBracket]",
  "]]" -> "\[RightDoubleBracket]",
  "<|" -> "\[LeftAssociation]",
  "|>" -> "\[RightAssociation]"
|>
```

For some reason when I updated Mathematica this option was not set. What's more confusing to me is that setting `AutoOperatorRenderings` had no effect whatsoever.

Note that this is a new feature of 12.3.1 and it is much better because

1. You can use it for `Part` delimiters and it will automatically detect when an expression is enclosed in parts
2. You can go back inside the rendered object and change it without having to delete the symbol and retype it
3. It is only a rendering so the underlying representation is unchanged

Comment: Thank you for the update. Today I downloaded Version 12.3, I couldn't see these updates in 12.1, and of course it is better.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, imho. This has fixed the problem for me, even across kernel restarts. Fantastic! Thanks so much for solving this problem!