# Keep Mathematica 12.3 from auto-formatting double square brackets?

Tags: front-end, editing, customization

I just updated to Mathematica 12.3.1.  Whenever I use the double square brackets used to specify Part, Mathematica now auto-formats them.  While the readability is nice, when I go to edit the code, I keep "missing" the place I want to edit because Mathematica expands the auto-formatted double square brackets to regular double brackets and now my cursor is in the wrong spot.  How do I keep Mathematica from auto-formatting double square brackets?  Is it an option somewhere in preferences that I'm just not seeing?

I want this

```
mylist[[i]]
```

instead of this

```
mylist〚i〛
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I think you mean version 12.3.1. Does [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/246400/58370) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [in V 12.3, expression in notebook shakes when scrolling mouse to edit them. How to stop this effect?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246400/in-v-12-3-expression-in-notebook-shakes-when-scrolling-mouse-to-edit-them-how)

Comment: I have voted to keep this question open, as it seems the trick in the _"duplicate"_ claim and in the current answer does not work in the latest versions of Mathematica, (see comments about `Inherited` values for ` "OperatorRenderings"`) and therefore does not answer the question.

Answer (score 8):

The new behavior of using ligatures for certain textual forms is controlled by this front end setting:

```
In[24]:= CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {StyleHints, "OperatorRenderings"}]

Out[24]= <|"|->" -> "\[Function]", "->" -> "\[Rule]", 
 ":>" -> "\[RuleDelayed]", "<=" -> "\[LessEqual]", 
 ">=" -> "\[GreaterEqual]", "!=" -> "\[NotEqual]", "==" -> "\[Equal]",
  "<->" -> "\[TwoWayRule]", "[[" -> "\[LeftDoubleBracket]", 
 "]]" -> "\[RightDoubleBracket]", "<|" -> "\[LeftAssociation]", 
 "|>" -> "\[RightAssociation]"|>
```

To remove only the double square bracket formatting you can use

```
With[
    {orig = CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {StyleHints, "OperatorRenderings"}]},
    CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {StyleHints, "OperatorRenderings"}] = KeyDrop[orig, {"[[", "]]"}]
]
```

or to disable all ligatures use

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {StyleHints, "OperatorRenderings"}] = {}
```

Comment: Interestingly, on my machine (v12.3.1.0 Win 10, 64-bit) the current value is `Inherited`. Any idea where I can set the parent from which notebooks actually inherit the default values?

Comment: @IstvánZachar, I might have made some change in my FE settings at one point.  If the code I posted here doesn't work for everyone it isn't as useful as I had thought.

Comment: I think your answer is a general and nice solution. It is probably my setup that digresses from default settings: `Inherited` causes no rendering at all. Actually, your answer helped me, as it shows how to set *any* value for stylehints, like `{}`, explicit default list, or any custom association of operator renderings (I prefer rendered arrows but not brackets).

Comment: I think this should be a simple menu option, not a complex set of commands to put things back the way they worked before

Comment: I get `Inherited ` in Wolfram Cloud too, and can't overwrite it's value.

Comment: @rhermans - do you see ligatures in the cloud?  Are you able to change *any* `CurrentValue` settings in the cloud?

Comment: @JasonB. Ligatures, yes, I think that is what they are, https://i.stack.imgur.com/dje0s.gif, don't have time to check further, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

I am running version 12.3.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 24, 2021). The answer by @JasonB using the `Association` formulation did not work for me. I deleted the "[[" and "]]" keys as shown, but all operator renderings remained. Wolfram Support told me to use a `List` instead of an `Association`, and now I can add or delete any operator rendering at will. For example,

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {StyleHints, "OperatorRenderings"}] =
   {"|->" -> "\[Function]",
    "->" -> "\[Rule]",
    ":>" -> "\[RuleDelayed]",
    "<=" -> "\[LessEqual]",
    ">=" -> "\[GreaterEqual]",
    "!=" -> "\[NotEqual]",
    "==" -> "\[Equal]",
    "<->" -> "\[TwoWayRule]",
    "<|" -> "\[LeftAssociation]",
    "|>" -> "\[RightAssociation]"
  }
```